# Rocker/Shiny not seeing apps after reboot

Tags: docker, shiny

What can be the reason for rocker/shiny to not recognize shiny apps in host OS?

I'm using rocker/shiny to experiment with shiny apps on windows.

This is how I start the image:

```
docker run -d -p 80:3838 -v D:/Projects/DockedShiny/apps/:/srv/shiny-server/ -v D:/Projects/DockedShiny/logs:/var/log/shiny-server/ rocker/shiny
```

I can see shiny was started:

```
C:\Users\Honza>docker logs gallant_thompson

*** warning - no files are being watched ***
[2019-02-08T06:49:04.860] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.9.1 (Node.js v8.11.3)
[2019-02-08T06:49:04.887] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2019-02-08T06:49:04.927] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2019-02-08T06:49:04.931] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
```

**Edit:** **Anybody has any hints what `*** warning - no files are being watched ***` exactly means**? I have suspition this might be a clue.

By inspecting the configuration I can see it's configured to files and folders that I specified during image startup:

```
root@778e307632ab:/etc/shiny-server# more shiny-server.conf
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Despite this the shiny web directory listing is empty and when specifying app by name (e.g. http://localhost/myapp) I'm getting 'page not found'. There is no new logs in Shiny log location.

The exact same scenario worked just fine for months. I recently needed to reboot my host machine and now I cannot make shiny to recognize my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSS: The issue was in recently changed username on affected machine. Docker is caching old one and that needed to be explicitly reset in docker settings -> Shared Drives menu

More details: https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/issues/59

Answer (score 1):

Server is complaining about running as root. I'd start by adding `--user shiny`. Also you're not sticking to a particular version but latest, and I can see the rocker/shiny image was updated a few days ago, so it could be broken or work different than previous version. I'd stick to 3.5.1 or whatever version you prefer, like `rocker/shiny:3.5.1`.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I changed the command to `docker run --user shiny -d -p 80:3838 -v D:/Projects/DockedShiny/apps/:/srv/shiny-server/ -v D:/Projects/DockedShiny/logs:/var/log/shiny-server/ rocker/shiny:3.5.1` the complaint about root user is gone (though it has been there befero when apps were loaded just fine); other than that log output is same and apps are still not loading :-/

Comment: The `warning - no files are being watched` in stdout is quite suspitious - I'm wondering what that means and if that might be a clue.

Comment: Maybe this can be of help https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/issues/58

Comment: thanks for tip. I do not experience the error from the mentioned issue. And the mentioned config line is already in my config.